# ListSelector Color after pressed an Item

Tags: android, android-listview, selection

I read a lot about ListSelector and selectors. But i cant figure out how to have the Item of a ListView having a different color **after** it got pressed.

In a Dual Fragment Layout the User clicks in Left ListView, data get loaded and presented in the right Fragment. To Keep the User Informed which item selected i want this to be highlighted until next item in the Left ListView gets pressed.

Do i need a custom State there ? How does the GMail App do this ?

thx

Answer (score 2):

Right, You need additional state there. I'm not sure, how GMail app is doing it, but default android Settings uses `android:state_activated="true"` state in their Selector for the list on tablets. Don't forget to set list `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"`.

Comment: Even when the other examples give me right results, i tend to to this, as it would be more generic and reusable.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this selector?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@color/message_item_read" />
```

Selector must be applyed to the item background, not to the listSelector.

Comment: Then try in your list adapter change item background, when item was pressed. There will be two selectors for item - one, if the item highlighted, and another one, when the item not highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for Android > 1.6 is:

in Activity:

```
public static int POS = -1;

...
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
...
POS = arg2;
...
}
```

in Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
int pos = MyActivity.POS;
if (pos == position){
convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lv_yellow);
}else{
convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lv_empty);
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was suffering with this issue myself... after working on it for long I found the solution and it's working for me. First of all create list_view_selector.xml under your drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Selector style for listrow -->
<item       
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_listview" />

<item   android:state_selected="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover_listview" />

<item   android:state_activated="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover_listview" />

 </selector>
```

Then the layout, which you use to fetch your list data you have to define list_view_selector. In my case I have defined like this:

```
//This is the adapter where I defined my customlistview
SimpleAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(
                this,
                list1,
                R.layout.customlistview,
                new String[] {"practice_technique","blank"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2}
                );


//This is my customlistview where I defined list_view_selector

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_view_selector" >


        <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"         
            style="@style/ListViewItemTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"   
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"      
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />


         <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"         
                android:textSize="12sp"         
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:textColor="#616162" 
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"       
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />


      </RelativeLayout>
```

Then at last onListItemclick you have to write something like this:

```
   protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
  {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        HashMap<String, String> val = list.get(position);           
        selectedTech = val.get("practice_technique");

        //below is the key line  
                v.setSelected(true);        
        startSelectedPage();
  }
```

Comment: Thx, i gave it a first quick run while heading home in the train. Looks good, will have a close look tommorrow. Looks like a generic aproach for me, thumbs up!

Comment: So, i had a closer look. But i dont understood why this works! I mean the color selection works, but i always see the color select where android:state_selected="false" is declared. In code i explicit say view.setSelected(true);

Comment: I dint understand you exactly?..u dont want item to be stay selected?

Comment: Yes. i want dem stay selected.

Comment: So by using above code , r u not able to do so?...cause thats what this code does.

Comment: @Shikhla Shah: Have a close look: U see the android:state_selected="false" and the method call v.setSelected(true);... this is some kind of irritating as them should not match, but it does, of course!

Answer (score 0):

Write your own ListAdapter to do this. Specifically I would extend ArrayAdapter, and put some code in this method:

```
 View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Essentially, this code will detect if the value has been clicked, and change the background color of the view. Now, how can you tell that a view has been clicked before? I suggest that you make your `ArrayAdapter` extend `OnClickListener`, and set the ListView's `setOnItemClickListener` to the custom `ArrayAdapter`. You can figure out which item was clicked by something like this:

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    //Note that position is the item which was clicked. 
  }
```