# initial state drawable list selector not working

Tags: android, selector

This is my code for the list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/darkgrey">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the list selector:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

  <item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
</selector>
```

My goal is to add a background to the list items: initial (no click happened and no focus)  -> a grey background. When pressed -> blue background. When released -> grey background.

But the initial background is not showing up. The grey background does not show up when opening the app and when you havent clicked an item yet. Someone knows how to fix this?

The java part:

```
package com.example.whs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Index extends Activity {

    public static final Object TITLE = "title";
    public static final Object SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
    public static final Object THUMBNAIL = "thumbnail";
    protected static final String POSITION = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);

        // Back actionbar icon enable
        //ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        //actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        buildMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.index, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //Builds the menu for listview
    public void buildMenu(){
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menu = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        //Arrays for info
        String[] menuTitleArray = {"Updates", "Gallerij"}; 
        String[] menuSubtitleArray = {"Bekijk updates", "Bekijk foto's en geef reacties", "Bekijk de updates"};
        String[] menuThumbnailArray = {"updates", "gallery"};
        for(int i=0; i < menuTitleArray.length; i++){
            // Build Hashmap for the item
            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
            item.put((String) TITLE, menuTitleArray[i]);
            item.put((String) SUBTITLE, menuSubtitleArray[i]);
            item.put((String) THUMBNAIL, menuThumbnailArray[i]);
            menu.add(item);
        }


        // Add adapter to the list
        MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(this, menu);
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);



        // Initialize the click event
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                switch(position){
                case 0:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Index.this, Updates.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474760/listselector-color-after-pressed-an-item
I had the same issue and found the solution from the above link, I used the solution by Shikha Shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's because the layout xml of your list row has it's own background set. And then your listSelector is successful set but get covered:)

Comment: is there a way to turn the background set off?

Comment: if you want to use listSelector, then set background of your row layout to @android:color/transparent

Comment: :S then try to set listSelector to @android:color/transparent and use the custom selector as background of your list row.

Comment: Really strange, could you post your Fragment or Activity that contain the listview?

Comment: the java part, not the xml

Comment: This is OK, Then the problem should be in MenuAdapter and it's layout~~

Comment: menuadapter has no layout, the only other layout is the layout for the listrows

Comment: here is the .java: http://pastebin.com/2J7xPD9T and the listrow: http://pastebin.com/4xabKUXg

Comment: vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null); R.layout.list_row is the real view that was shown as the list row, change the background of it to your custom selector

Comment: it works with vi.setBackgroundResource(activity.getResources().getIdentifier("list_selector", "drawable", Index.class.getPackage().getName())); Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use your `android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"` in your `custom item layout` you used for `ListView` items.

Like you have your `ListView` here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@color/darkgrey">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

and it is using following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**

You can also use selector like

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal"></item>
```

Comment: but you do have to use this in the listview, dont you?

Comment: yes, it needed. But if problem occur, you can also use this scenario.

Comment: i think my list_selector is wrong, what states do i have to implement?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wish to add selector on list row, not on ListView :)
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector) for you.